# I would like to understand the effect of the parts of speech of the Hebrew in Isaiah 58:12 on its meaning

Tags: hebrew, isaiah, figure-of-speech

I looked it up but cannot understand what those mean. e.g., preposition, masculine singular, etc., as shown in the interlinear below.

[image: Screenshot of the interlinear for Isaiah 58:12]

What do those grammatical notations indicate?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  I suggest you get a good text on grammar, or dictionary to explain terms like, "preposition", "masculine":, "singular", "noun", "verb", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Those are parts of speech (grammar)

verbs are broken down into the contexts in which they are used:

- Conjugation: Different endings convey different aspects of the verb (intensive, causative, reflexive, etc). Here it's a normal verb "build" (in Qal)
- Tense: In Hebrew there are two tenses, Perfect and imperfect.  Here, even though it's perfect, with a 'waw' in front, it flips the force of the verb, making it imperfect (or future and continuous-oriented)
- Person:  In Hebrew there are (as in English) 1st, 2nd, and 3rd person referents (for both singular and plural)
- Gender: in Hebrew there are only two options: Masculine and Feminine (no neuter option)

It gets more complicated from there.  I strongly suggest, that if you're interested in the biblical languages it would be wise find a pastor who knows these and sit down with him and figure out a plan for you to learn them.  As you can see, with just verbs, it is complicated.  The same sorts of categories and subcategories exist for nouns, adjectives, prepositions and other parts of speech.

Comment: Conjugation is the entire inflection of a verb, including tense (aspect), person, gender, number, and binyan. You should replace "conjugation" with "binyan" in your answer.